# DataIntegrityViolationException from concurrent access

Tags: sql, slick

I have a table that has a unique index constraint on two columns. My bit of code that does the check and insert into the database is as below:

```
def createNewEntry(myTableType: MyTableType) = database withSession { implicit session: Session =>

  val autoInc = myTableElems returning myTableElems.map(_.elemId)

  getElemForId(myTableType.elemId) match {
    case Some(oldTableType) =>
      if (oldTableType.isModified(myTableType))
        myTableElems.insert(myTableType.copy(version = oldTableType.version + 1))
    case None =>
      autoInc.insert(myTableType)
  }
  getElemForId(myTableType.elemId)
}
```

Is there any possibility that the above code could result in a DataIntegrityViolation exception because of concurrent access tp the above method? I have a unique index defined on a column called name and another column called version. Every time I call this createNewEntry method, I check if one exists if yes, I copy everything, increment the version and insert the new version in the database.

Since I'm using Slick for database access, the above method works within a database transaction context and in auto commit mode.

My table with entries in the database would look like:

```
id name version
1  abc  1
2  xyz  1
3  abc  2
```

name and version has unique index constraint enforced!

Now the question is could there be a scenario where I could have a DataIntegrityViolation exception? Should I guard against it?

Comment: Yes, incrementing this way will cause problems - two concurrent calls could derive the same new version number and the latter would fail with a PK / Unique constraint violation. Rather use the RDBMS's native increment mechanism, e.g. `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySql or `Identity` in Sql Server + Oracle. (A transaction would typically be `READ COMMITTED` isolation which will not prevent other concurrent readers from obtaining the same version)

Comment: The version can't be an AUTO_INCREMENT field as this needs to be done per entry! What are the other possibilities that I have other than locking the above piece of code? See the table structure in my post above!